# how to import a text from that list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am new to flutter and i need your help with that issue 
 I want to **import the item** from this **list**=>

```
List values = [
  {"category":'موبيلات',
   'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
   'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},
  {'category':'موبيلات',
   'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
   'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},
  {'category':'موبيلات',
   'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
   'categoryimage':'images/iphone'},
  {'category':'موبيلات',
   'categorybackimage':'images/backgroundimage',
   'categoryimage':'images/iphone'}
];
```

that what i've tried=>

```
 Text("${(values['category'])}"),
 Card(color: Colors.white,
      child: 
      Text( "عروض ", 
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
```

but there is an **error** says
=>

```
the argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
```

why does that error appears and how to fix things and if there is other ways please help me with it

Comment: Error suggest that you are using int in place of string

Comment: i fixed that issue by using index but it gives me an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ListView.builder` for this it is used to create a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on-demand:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: values.length,
  itembuilder: (context, i) => Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Text(
    values[i]['category'],
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: it gives me exceptions and says```I/flutter (30667): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 5
I/flutter (30667): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 6
I/flutter (30667): Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 7
```

Comment: it works when i replace the ```index``` with ```0``` but images don't appear

Comment: ```child: Stack(
children: <Widget>[
                                ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                      child: Image.asset(values[0]['categorybackimage'],fit: BoxFit.fill, )),
                                    Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("${(values[0]['category'])}"),```

Comment: Make sure that your images are in assets folder and all the images reference is present pubspec.yaml as well

Comment: i did that but still nothing happens

Comment: It looks like your images are in images directory, which is placed in flutter app directory, so make sure that the same path is given in pubspec.yaml